# Strange non English characters in String, error on server

Tags: php, android, server

First of all, my code is working...but the resultant file is causing problems on my server.  Only files with strange characters are causing errors on the server, such as file does not exist or error connecting to file when trying to open the file through FTP.  All files without strange characters are working fine on the server, and can be opened and edited.

Here's my workflow:

1. Get text from a `TextView` on user's screen, run it through this code to remove unwanted characters:

`replaceAll("[^a-z ,()A-Z0-9]+", "-");`

2. Create a text file using this text as the file name;
3. Upload this text file to server with this PHP script:

   ```
   <?php

   $file_path = "uploads/";

   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
   echo "success";
   } else{
   echo "fail";
   }
   ?>
   ```

The filenames are containing these strange characters, I assume due to non English characters on the user's screen.

[image]

I need to be careful because the path to upload the file to my server is based on this file name and I don't know how to test it with non English characters.  Any help is much appreciated.  I need to remove/replace any non English characters without messing up the file path.

Comment: It is because the characters you sent from the device are not encoded. Please encode it using UTF-8 and in the server side you can decode it.

Comment: Can you please help in how to do this?

Comment: I recommend you to follow this [tutorial](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89)

Comment: That looks great, I will try that.  Thank you.

Comment: This is working great, thank you, but I am left with file names that include the %2F: `name=%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FServerError%2F105`.  How can I remove these and keep spaces before writing the file name?  Pleasse see my PHP above...thank you, please help.

Comment: Hey did you decode the param on your php side.? Like this  $name   = urldecode($_POST['name']);

Comment: The issue may happen because of
1.You may not be using POST method to send data to php server
2.A file name can't contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? < > |

Comment: @LvN I have tried adding that line to PHP and there is no change.  Can you please look at my PHP above and post the whole thing?...I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can solve this by converting string on server to UTF-8 using mb_convert_encoding, but really your code is very not safe, as you are using a passed user variable as a file path, and hackers can send /../../../ and so forth.
The solution I use for both, is to convert on server the passed file name to a hex string, using bin2hex. That way you have a very safe file name, with no encoding issues.

Comment: You have a great point, but unfortunately I have no experience in this and don't know how to do this.  The text file name is generated in my code (based on a text field that the app creates) and the user never sees it; it contains error data that I can use, but I see your point how unsafe this can be.  Thank you for your reply...

Comment: $file_path = $file_path . bin2hex(basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']));

Comment: That seems to be working, but I cannot duplicate the strange characters being generated (without your fix), even adding other languages from my app.  Any idea how to test this?

Answer (score -1):

**Use this line its help you.**

String styledText = Your File Name;

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));

Comment: `fromHtml` is depricated